# Running django in a virtualenv with python 3 on OSX

Tags: django, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv

I created a python3 virtual environment but when I'm in my virtualenv and I type:

> python -V

I get:

> Python 2.7.12

If I want to run my server with command:

> python manage.py runserver

It gives me error:

> File "manage.py", line 17, in 
>       "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
>   ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

But when I run:

> python3 manage.py runserver

It works perfectly!?!

**Why does it still want to run python 2 if it's a python 3 environment 
?**

Comment: Have you activated the Python virtual environment? What command did you use to create it? If virtualenv was originally installed for Python 2, you need to have supplied ``--python python3`` option to virtualenv to have it create a virtual environment that uses Python 3.

Comment: Yes Graham the virtual environment was activated. I used `source bin/activate` to activate it. The virtual environment was created in Python 3  I used the command `virtualenv testEnv -p python3` but still once activated it uses Python 2 if only `python` is used as a command.

Comment: If you run ``which python`` does it come from the virtual environment. The ``virtualenv`` program should still leave ``python`` as being the same as ``python3`` when virtual environment is for Python 3.

Comment: Well the results are different because after activating my virtual environment and run `which python` I get: `/Users/usr/Documents/_LESSONS/PYTHON/_Virtualenv/test/bin/python` and when I run `which python3` I get `/Users/usr/Documents/_LESSONS/PYTHON/_Virtualenv/test/bin/python3`. Should they not be the same if I set my virtual environment for Python 3?

Comment: Do ``ls -las /Users/usr/Documents/_LESSONS/PYTHON/_Virtualenv/test/bin``. They are different program names so they path cannot be the same, but if you look in the ``bin`` directory, one should be a symlink to the other.

Comment: Indeed python links to python3 and python3.5 links to python3. So why is the python command not working? Or shouldn't I be bothered about it?

Comment: I can only suggest to delete the virtual environment, recreate it and reinstall your packages.

Comment: Thx Graham, tried it already several time but still the same problem. But I'll just use the python3 to run the server. As I'm a newb I'll mabey figure it out later. thx already.

Comment: Are you using Apple's Python installation, or have you installed different version from python.org or Brew. With Brew especially if playing with multiple Python versions have seen the Brew installation itself get screwed up.

Comment: I'm using Apple version and Python 3.5.2 from python.org. But for the virtual environments the latest Pyhton version is always first downloaded and then installed automatically. I'm not using the Apple version nor the self installed 3.5.2 version in the virtual environments.

Comment: You mean you are using ``pyenv`` (not ``pyvenv``)? When you use ``virtualenv`` or ``pyvenv`` it doesn't download the latest Python version. The only tool like that is ``pyenv`` which will install a specific Python version for you, but then not create a virtual environment, that is still a separate step.

Comment: Never heard of pyenv and pyvenv! ;) I just followed this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FshRArXrEcM&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQGhFKEwRV10uLNGYh-pAH6) and they don't talk about pyenv and pyvenv. LIke you see in the tutorial they use virtualenv. The command I ran was `virtualenv testEnv -p python3`. By seeing a progress bar in the terminal while installing I assumed it was downloading python3. But it's getting complicated. ;) I just followed the tutorial and there they run the commands only using python instead of python3. That's why I figured I was doing something wrong.